# issue with dashboard duplicates in superset

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am a beginner at Superset. While working I came across an issue i.e. when I am creating a same dashboard but not creating in the same name dashboards.  Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need response please . i create a one dashboard . The dashboard with the same name as the dashboard we made create should not be create like duplicates are not allowed.